# Threejs: compute projected coordinate in fragment shader

Tags: three.js, glsl, shader, fragment-shader, perspectivecamera

I'm struggling with handling Coord in fragment Shader.
In brief, I just want to draw circle with fragment shader using `(x,y,z)` of world space. But because of camera position and the `z` of circle's center position, I cannot get actual right projected `x` and `y` coords.

Let's suppose that my camera placed at `(0, 0, 1000)` and perspective with

- fov: 45deg
- aspect with `screen_width/screen_height`
- nearZ: 1
- farZ: 10000

Camera look at `(0,0)`. In this case with `three.js`, I can get `projectionMatrix` and `ModelViewMatrix` of camera(e.g.`PerspectiveCamera.projectionMatrix`) and also in default I can use `viewMatrix` in fragmentShader of `ShaderMaterial` in `three.js`.

So in fragmentShader, for calculating projected coordinate of circle placed `(300, 300, -1000)`, I write my `VertexShader` and `FragmentShader` like below.

My Vertex Shader is only for get `projectionMatrix` and `modelViewMatrix` as `P` and `MV`.

```
// vertexShader
varying mat4 P;
varying mat4 MV;
void main(){
    P = projectionMatrix;
    MV = modelViewMatrix;
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
}
```

And then, I just calculate x and y using `P` and `MV` like below.

```
// fragmentShader
varying mat4 P;
varying mat4 MV;
uniform float x;
uniform float y;
uniform float z;
uniform float r;
uniform vec2 u_resolution;

float circle(vec2 _st, vec2 _center, float _radius){
    vec2 dist = _st - _center + u_resolution;
    return 1.-smoothstep(_radius-(_radius*0.01),
                     _radius+(_radius*0.01),
                     length(dist));
}

void main(){
    vec2 coord = (P * MV * vec4(x, y, z, 1.0)).xy;
    float point = circle(gl_FragCoord.xy, coord, r); // ignore r scaling.
    gl_FragColor = vec4(vec4(point), point);
}
```

But the result doesn't match what I expected. And also some weird behaviors were found.

- No matter what `z` of uniform, there's no change at all.
- Pixel ratio can be some reason(e.g. retina display has pixel ratio as 2) but from my experiments of it, it has nothing to do with this.

Any mistake that I made? Or any misleading? (somehow there can be mistake in `circle` function but I think it doesn't make critical problem..)

Comment: Waht is `u_resolution` and what do you expect by `_st - _center + u_resolution`? Shouldn't it be something like `(_st - _center) / u_resolution`? And note, `gl_FragCoord.xy` are window (pixel) coordinates.

Comment: Hi. I expect circle placed at `(x,y)` and because gl_FragCoord start at (0,0) from left bottom corner, I added u_resolution(It's also because the `_center` is coordinates from (0,0) meaning center of screen.

Comment: Why are your projection and modelView matrices passed on as `varying`s?

Comment: I thought Three js passes `projectionMatrix` and `modelView` according to its camera settings and Mesh. So, instead of calculating them manually, I just passed it down to fragment shader.

Comment: Well, most likely, your matrices are `uniform`s to begin with, so they are already available to all shader stages in the program, and passing them as `varying`s is just a huge waste of ressources.

Comment: But the main issue here is that your calculations don't make any sense. You try to define a circle by using the _clip space_ position of the origin and the _window space_ fragment coords. What is unclear to me is what you actually trying to achieve: an actual 2D, undistorted cicrle, or the proper perspectively correct image of some circle.

Comment: Okay really thanks to your comments. What I want to do is making an actual 2D circle from world space's coordinates (x,y,z). This circle don't need to be seen as distored and perspective. It just need to be seen like Mesh from CircleGeometry at (x,y,z). So, could I ask it is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets assume that `x`, `y` and `z`, define the center of a circle in world space. You want to draw a circle in a plane which is parallel to the view port in a screen space pass, where you draw a quad over the entire viewport.

You have to transform the center of the circle from world space coordinates to normalized device coordinates. The best solution would be to do this on the CPU and to set uniform with the result.

According to the code of your question, this can be done in the vertex shader, too. But you have to do a [Perspective divide](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Post-Processing#Perspective_divide), after the transformation by the model view matrix and the projection matrix, to transform the point form clip space to view normalized device space:

```
uniform mat4 P;
uniform mat4 MV;
uniform float x;
uniform float y;
uniform float z;

varying vec3 cpt; 

void main(){
    vec4 cpt_h  =  projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(x, y, z, 1.0);
    vec3 cpt    =  cpt_h.xyz / cpt_h.w;
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
}
```

If `u_resolution`, is the width and the height of the viewport, then the  x and y coordinate of the fragment in normalized device space can be calculated by:

```
vec2 coord = gl_FragCoord.xy / u_resolution.xy * 2.0 - 1.0;
```

But I recommend to transform the center point of the circle to window (pixel) coordinates, then the radius can be set in pixel, too:

```
vec2 cpt_p = (cpt.xy * 0.5 + 0.5) * u_resolution.xy;
```

To calculate the length of a vector you can use the GLSL function [`length`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/length.xhtml).

The final fragment shader may look like this:

```
varying vec3 cpt; 

uniform vec2 u_resolution;

uniform float u_pixel_ratio; // device pixel ratio

uniform float r; // e.g. 100.0 means a radius of 100 pixel

float circle( vec2 _st, vec2 _center, float _radius )
{
    // thickness of the circle in pixel
    const float thickness = 20.0;

    // distance to the center  point in pixel
    float dist = length(_st - _center);

    return 1.0 - smoothstep(0.0, thickness/2.0, abs(_radius-dist));
}

void main(){
    vec2  cpt_p  = (cpt.xy * 0.5 + 0.5) * u_resolution.xy * u_pixel_ratio;
    float point  = circle(gl_FragCoord.xy, cpt_p, r);
    gl_FragColor = vec4(point);
}
```

e.g. a circle with a radius of 50.0 and a thickness of 20.0:

[image]

---

If you want to apply a perspective distortion to the circle, this means the size of the circle decreases by distance, then you have to set the radius `r` in world coordinates.
Calculate a point on the circle and calculate the distance of the point to the center point of the circle in the vertex shader in normalized device space.
This is the radius which you have to pass from the vertex shader to the fragment shader additional to the center point of the circle.

```
uniform mat4 P;
uniform mat4 MV;
uniform float x;
uniform float y;
uniform float z;
uniform float r; // e.g. radius in world space

varying vec3  cpt;
varying float radius;

void main(){
    vec4 cpt_v  = modelViewMatrix * vec4(x, y, z, 1.0);
    vec4 rpt_v  = vec4(cpt_v.x, cpt_v.y + r, cpt_v.zw);

    vec4 cpt_h  = projectionMatrix * cpt_v;
    vec4 rpt_h  = projectionMatrix * rpt_v;

    cpt         =  cpt_h.xyz / cpt_h.w;
    vec3 rpt    =  rpt_v.xyz / rpt_v.w;
    radius      =  length(rpt-cpt);

    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
}
```

```
varying vec3  cpt;
varying float radius;

uniform vec2 u_resolution;
uniform float u_pixel_ratio; // device pixel ratio

uniform float r; // e.g. 100.0 means a radius of 100 pixel

float circle( vec2 _st, vec2 _center, float _radius )
{
    const float thickness = 20.0;
    float dist = length(_st - _center);
    return 1.0 - smoothstep(0.0, thickness/2.0, abs(_radius-dist));
}

void main()
{
    vec2  cpt_p    = (cpt.xy * 0.5 + 0.5) * u_resolution.xy * u_pixel_ratio;
    float radius_p = radius * 0.5 * u_resolution.y * u_pixel_ratio.y;

    float point  = circle(gl_FragCoord.xy, cpt_p, radius_p);
    gl_FragColor = vec4(point);
}
```

Comment: Your answer is out of this world! Really thanks for your contribution! I learn that I didn't know like 'perspective division' which could be totally crucial for this problem. Also I edit some typo in code of yours. If you don't mind, could you recommend some resources related to this issue or basic concept knowledge about gl?

Comment: Sorry for bothering you but it's just curious about what if I want to draw distorted circle as @derhass mentioned?

Comment: @Hyuntak.Cha Do you mean that the radius of the circle has to decrease by the distance?

Comment: yes it was and from your code, I wonder why we just calculate radius_p from 'y'. Isn't distortion along with the x direction also be seen? (Also I found some mistake in code: `u_pixel_ratio.y`. Its type is float.